# Why Fortran is slow in the julia benchmark "rand_mat_mul"?

Tags: numpy, fortran, julia, blas

Benchmark test results on the home page of Julia (http://julialang.org/) shows that Fortran is about 4x slower than Julia/Numpy in the "rand_mat_mul" benchmark.

**I can not understand that why fortran is slower while calling from the same fortran library (BLAS)??**

I have also performed a simple test for matrix multiplication evolving fortran, julia and numpy and got the similar results:

Julia

```
n = 1000; A = rand(n,n); B = rand(n,n);
@time C = A*B;
```

> >> elapsed time: 0.069577896 seconds (7 MB allocated)

Numpy in IPython

```
from numpy import *
n = 1000; A = random.rand(n,n); B = random.rand(n,n);
%time C = dot(A,B);
```

> >> Wall time: 98 ms

Fortran

```
PROGRAM TEST

IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N = 1000
INTEGER :: I,J
REAL*8 :: T0,T1

REAL*8 :: A(N,N), B(N,N), C(N,N)

CALL RANDOM_SEED()
DO I = 1, N, 1
    DO J = 1, N, 1
        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(A(I,J))
        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(B(I,J))
    END DO
END DO

call cpu_time(t0)
CALL DGEMM ( "N", "N", N, N, N, 1.D0, A, N, B, N, 0.D0, C, N )
call cpu_time(t1)

write(unit=*, fmt="(a24,f10.3,a1)") "Time for Multiplication:",t1-t0,"s"

END PROGRAM TEST
```

> gfortran test_blas.f90 libopenblas.dll -O3 & a.exe
>
> >> Time for Multiplication:     0.296s

Comment: I do not know about julia's test case, but the example matrices are very small. You should use bigger matrices. Also check the threads used.

Comment: You should not use `cpu_time`, but `system_clock`, this doesn't tell anything.

Comment: This is a good question – if someone figures out anything wrong with the Fortran version, we should fix it. @VladimirF, what's the difference between the `cpu_time` and `system_clock` functions?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski `cpu_time` will sum cpu_times of all threads, `system_clock` returns the elapsed wall clock time. It is nonsense to compare the other results with `cpu_time` here.

Comment: That does seem like a problem. Discussion also ongoing here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10157.

Comment: BTW on my computer the Fortran test gives `0.070 s`.

Comment: Wow, a benchmark posted on the Julia site which shows that Fortran is slower than Julia !

Comment: @Vladimir F   Thank you very much to point point out the key issue. Besides, you computer is much more stronger than mine ...

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the timing function to system_clock() and result turns out to be (I run it five times in one program)

> Time for Multiplication:  92ms
>
> Time for Multiplication:  92ms
>
> Time for Multiplication:  89ms
>
> Time for Multiplication:  85ms
>
> Time for Multiplication:  94ms

It is approximate as Numpy, but still about 20% slower than Julia.

Comment: Make sure you use the same BLAS binary and the same Fortran runtime library, then you will find out the difference probably disappears. A lot of time can be actually spend just by parsing the character arguments and not by the computation. BTW the misuse of `cpu_time()` is a common source of errors and questions on this site.